# how to enable hardware acceleration in windows phone?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I had created application a simple game, like Flow Connect you find on android device, But it seems little slow during drawing lines, So I want to enable the GPU or enable the hardware acceleration so that the application would perform fast in windows phone, Where should the hardware acceleration be done, in XAML file or somewhere else.

Comment: Hardware acceleration is automatic. From there, it's a matter of knowing how to benefit from it. Have a look at articles about the "compositor thread" to understand how it works. But to cut to the point, for the hardware acceleration to be effectively used, you need to use storyboards and render-transforms when animating your elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code

try it out

```
    1. Enable composition caching at the plug-in level by setting the EnableGPUAcceleration parameter to “true”.

<param name="EnableGPUAcceleration" value="true" />

2. You can now enable GPU acceleration on the element(s) you wish to cache by specifying a CacheMode value of BitmapCache on the object or container of objects.

<StackPanel   CacheMode="BitmapCache" … />
```

Heres a blog for gpu acceleration in windows phone and silverlight

[hardware acceleration windows phone and silverlight](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2009/07/09/silverlight-cached-composition.aspx?Redirected=true)

Comment: <param name="EnableGPUAcceleration" value="true" /> is for silverlight at the html level this is not applicable for windows phone. On windows phone you can actually see the reasonly value of this parameter called Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableGPUAcceleration which is actually always true.

Comment: and does this help <StackPanel   CacheMode="BitmapCache" … />

Comment: This should help but only for UIElement which the content don't need to be reendered constantly (static content like geometries) and in combination with Storyboard and RenderTransform like @Kookiz said

Comment: You can use Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableCacheVisualization = true; to check what is harware accelerated and what is not

Comment: But the link I found said it is for both silverlight and windows phone. As of common sense I knew that in windows phone such extreme features might not be available but. Since dont have a device could not go through . Thanks for this information :)

Comment: Just to clarify what I said, what is describe in the article about BitmapCache apply too, and you cannot change EnableGPUAcceleration because it's always enabled

Comment: Also the article is not saying that it apply to windows phone too, the "Silverlight and Windows Phone SDK" which appear at the top is the name of the blog, the article actually don't mention windows phone anywhere (And is from 2009 which is before the first wp :) )